# How get location by COARSE location

Tags: android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, currentlocation

I'm trying to develo an app that get location by COARSE location. This app must run on Android 6 too than i've implemented permission request on run time, start the map but i can't get my current location... any tips?

This is my main activity:

```
package com.luca.fontanelle;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String providerNetwork = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();}

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude())));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));

    }


    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (controllaPermessi()) {
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                            builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    //final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            //...
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.

                            Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            //...
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

       /*     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }*/
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }else{
            richiestaPermessi();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //Log.d("MapsActivity", "Connessione fallita. Codice di errore: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    private boolean controllaPermessi(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void richiestaPermessi(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attiva la localizzazione per usufruire dell'app.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permessi accettati. Puoi usare tutte le funzionalità.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permessi non accettati. Non puoi accedere alle funzionalità del GPS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luca.fontanelle">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.luca.fontanelle.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At the monitor i found this:

5-05 11:00:45.283 18178-18178/com.luca.fontanelle E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-05 11:00:45.283 18178-18178/com.luca.fontanelle E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-05 11:00:45.307 18178-18217/com.luca.fontanelle E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

Comment: yes.. and set it on google_maps_api.xml

Comment: Did you mean that you are getting the location as null?

Comment: The map starts, i got the mark setted on onMapReady method but my position isn't shown.. If you want in can share the project..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with google fused location api

1) MainActivity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    protected final static String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
    protected final static String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;
    private boolean mycheck, chrckonce;
    private LocationManager manager;
    private Double lat, lng;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = MainActivity.this;

        chrckonce = true;

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLastUpdateTime = "";
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))) {

            //GPS is not available show alert
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS SETTINGS");
            alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enable! Want to go to settings menu?");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(" Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();

        } else {

            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            mycheck = true;

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        if (chrckonce) {

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lng)), 2000, null);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 18));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            chrckonce = false;
        }
    }


    //Update location from google fused api
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LOCATION_KEY)) {
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(LOCATION_KEY);
            }
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY);
            }
        }
    }

    //synchronized google fused location api
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    //create location request
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }


    //on resume activity
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mycheck == true) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
    }

    //when activity goes on pause
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mycheck == true) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                stopLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
    }

    //when activity stops
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mycheck == true) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

        }
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    //check connection suspended
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    //Location update
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    //location update close when activity closed
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

2) activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </fragment>


</LinearLayout>
```

In Manifest permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Also you can change priority by change this line after LocationRequest setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

Comment: I don't need gps so can i remove FINE_LOCATION permissions?. Does it still works? I'll test in an hour.

Comment: Google fused location api used both GPS and NETWORK depend upon indoor and outdoor position and conserve battery life.Please see the video you will know how google fused location Api works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc

Comment: Thanks for the video!! is very useful! My english is not very good and I'm asking confirm: the guy (min 17:50) says that balanced accuracy is used for network location (means WIFI and 4G). Is that right? If so, my specs asks to use only WIFI and 4G. Your code (that works fine) asks to enable gps. So if i change if (!manager.isProviderEnabled((LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))) with ....LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER it checks only if network is enabled? I hope that I explain well what I need.. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: yes i understand want you want yoshi but google fused api automatically used network or GPS or WIFI depend upon the position like indoor or outdoor for use just network provider just use location manager with network provider not fused api because fused made by fusing WIFI , GPS , Netwotk and sensors if you want code i will provide you

Comment: Thanks again! I solved the problem setting Balanced Accuracy that works only with network and checking if network provider is enabled. As said in the video: "balanced accuracy DOESN'T use gps but works with WIFI and 4G". I tried with these settings, DISABLING GPS, and I got position. Of course the position isn't really precise (as known) but is what i want!

Comment: Thanks for telling me that params

Comment: I'm trying to make it works on android 6 but I'have some trouble with permissions.. I've read that I can use in manifest.xml uses-permission-sdk-23 instead of uses-permission but it won't work. How can I set up the permission control?

Comment: yes you have to define run time permission for android 6 in your code (java class ) not in manifest