# onLocationChanged not fired even though the smartphone moves

Tags: android, github, gps, location

My final target is an app for android which shall show the smartphone’s moving position when carried by a player on a golf course. (From that location point, several information like distances to the flag and bunkers will be calculated and illustrated.)
As a first step I want to realize an app which indicates the smartphone location on a Google map. My investigations brought me to a sample code in Github:
 (Android Location Example: https://github.com/treehouse/android-location-example)
I was able to get this code running in my Android Studio 2.0 environment. (I am not working with an emulator but a true hardware connected via usb cable.) Then, based on another recommendation from a stackoverflow member, I refined it with a code line which shall cause that the location is illustrated in form of a blue circle on the map (as in the Google standard app). I added the line:
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

When I move around with the smartphone, I can see in the app how the blue circle is moving to my new position over the Google map.
The big disappointment however is that these location changes do not get reflected within my code lines. My expectation has been that whenever the device notices a location change, the relevant (sounding) function in the code “ onLocationChanged(Location location)” is triggered and the new location position data can be retrieved. But actually this function is not triggered by the location move. I have used several methods to find out whether these lines are processed (writing log records, debug, make a sound…) but I cannot find any trace. As long as I cannot achieve to catch the location changes in my code, the entire function will be useless.

I am just starting to work with Android Studio and the various google libraries and therefore lack experience. Can somebody let me know what my wrong assumption is? ( I guess I am missing a more conceptual layer in my understanding. Sorry.)

Of course if someone could guide me to the necessary code change to achieve my functional target as described above, this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you're working with so others can spot problems or attempt to reproduce your issue. See: **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: so are you saying handleNewLocation method works because the map is updating? can you not grab the current location from that Location object?

Comment: See that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047269/how-get-location-by-coarse-location/37048611#37048611  get your current and changes location using google fused api

Comment: Dear Abhay, Thanks a lot for your advice. I used the Code as suggested in the link above (37047269) and got it working.